# Getting a false boolean output for if(isset($_POST['occupation'])) when it shouldn't be null

Tags: php, html, forms, tags

I'm just trying to post a simple form. When I `dump_var($_POST)` I'm getting **NULL** values for `['occupation']`, `['email']`, and `['job']`. The others are still working somehow. I can't find a difference in how I'm writing the ones that are working and the ones that aren't. Any ideas of what's happening?
Thanks!

This is what I have written for the form:

```
<form name= "form1"  method="post">

Name: <br/>
  <input type ="text" name ="name" value='<?php if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    echo $_POST["name"];}?>'>
    <br/><br/>
 E-mail: <br/>
  <input type= "text" name= "email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){
   echo $_POST['email'];}?>"/>
   <br/><br/>
Mailing address: <br/>
 <input type= "text" name= "mail" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
  echo $_POST['mail'];}?>"/>
  <br/><br/>
Occupation: <br/>
 <input type="text" name="occupation" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['occupation'])){echo $_POST['occupation'];}?>">
    <br/><br/>
Phone: <br/> 
  <input type= "text" name= "phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
    echo $_POST['phone'];}?>"/>
<br/><br/>
Job Title: <br/>
 <input type= "text" name ="job" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['job'])){
  echo $_POST['job'];}?>"/>
  <br/><br/>
 <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value= "submit"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: try to close each input with '/>' - you seem to  randomly use '>' and '/>' closing brackets.

Comment: Yeah, they're so random because i kept switching then around hoping they were  the problem. I changed them all to '/>'  and it's still acting the same way. Any other ideas? Thanks!